# Alpinejs: change values inside children from parent element

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have some nested custom select menus by alpinejs:

```
<template x-for="(attribute, rootindex) in attributes">
    <div x-ref="attribute.name"
     x-data="{open: false, selectedIndex: false, activeIndex: null, selectedItem:false, items:[...], placeholder:'Choose '+attribute.label }"
     class="my-5">
     ...
```

you can see each child has its own states/variables like open, selectedIndex, selectedItem, ...
in a situations I want to set some of these states:

I tried using x-ref on childs but it wont work and it will return undefined!
this function is at parent level:

```
    deleteAttribute(index) {
      for (let i = index; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
        delete this.selected[this.attributes[i].name];
        this.$refs[this.attributes[i].name].selectedItem = false;
      }
```

Could you please tell me how can access children states?
for example I want to set some of the 'selectedItem' to false in specific children

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could use Alpine.$data(element) api

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
  <script>
    let data = {
      attrs: [{
          key: 'no1',
          name: 'first'
        },
        {
          key: 'no2',
          name: 'second'
        },
        {
          key: 'no3',
          name: 'third'
        }
      ],
      toggle(index) {
        let el = document.getElementById(`child-${index}`)
        let data = Alpine.$data(el)
        data.selected = !data.selected
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body x-data="data">
  <template x-for="(attr, index) of attrs">
    <div x-data="{selected: false}">
      <p :id='`child-${index}`' x-text="attr.name + (selected ? '[x]' : '[-]')"></p><button @click="toggle(index)">Toggle </button>
    </div>
  </template>
</body>
```